# Push notifications para iOS

Tags: push-notification

Estou utilizando alguns serviços para envios de *push notifications*. Porém, nenhum deles funciona para iOS.

Ou seja, browser no iOS não notificam o usuário.

Isso seria algo do **WebKit** do Safari?

Comment: Esta falando de Apps hibridos ou PWA ou do navegador Safari mesmo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento falo em navegadores mesmo. Em PWA funciona?

Comment: @FelipeGoulart PWA em iOS ainda é precário. Sobre notificação: https://caniuse.com/#search=notification - https://whatwebcando.today/push-notifications.html e a solução proprietaria da Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1

Comment: @FelipeGoulart como o Bacco mencionou outro dia no chat, o suporte para Worker no iOs ainda é meio precário (estou usando iOS11 preciso ver como esta atualmente), mas sobre o push especificamente creio que não tenha suporte, pois provavelmente deve valer o que o link do bacco indica. A necessidade é ser web mesmo?

Comment: @Bacco pelo que vi existe uma forma. Mas, é quase como configurar um aplicativo.

Comment: Sim, tem que usar o sistema proprietário da apple, é um inferno - a apple nao quer que vc fique independente da loja

Comment: @Bacco mas pelo menos tem uma forma. O problema é que terei que fazer tudo separado. Pois, irei usar serviço de terceiros para tal. Com a Apple vai ter que ser na mão mesmo. E acho que não vou conseguir criar segmentações também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Será que rolaria com PWA?

Comment: Tem que fazer as contas. Dependendo do trabalho que vai dar, já parte pra App nativo mesmo

Comment: Faço das palavras do @Bacco as minhas, mas já adianto, se for criar um webView proprio vai ter que manipular o JavaScriptInterface para conseguir algo mais eficiente, se for Cordova (e/ou Ionic, que basicamente é cordova) e os pushs forem em background, pode usar isto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-push (só pra constar se for Ionic já tem até coisa semi-pronta: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/)